# Find the limit of $n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)$, where $a_n=\frac{(\ln n)^{10}}{n^{1.1}}$

Tags: limits

How do I go about solving this limit?

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(n\left(\frac{\left(\frac{\left(ln\left(n\right)\right)^{10}}{n^{1.1}}\right)}{\frac{\left(ln\left(n+1\right)\right)^{10}}{\left(n+1\right)^{1.1}}}-1\right)\right)$$

Symbolab says its 1.1 but I can't seem to crack it.

Comment: What did you do to solve this, except typing the formula in a symbolic calculator?

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:**
Rewrite
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{\left(\ln\left(n\right)\right)^{10}}{n^{1.1}}\right)}{\frac{\left(\ln\left(n+1\right)\right)^{10}}{\left(n+1\right)^{1.1}}}-1
=
\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{1.1}\left(\frac{\ln n}{\ln(n+1)}\right)^{10} - 1
= 
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{1.1}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})}{\ln n}}\right)^{10} - 1
$$ 
and do a [Taylor expansion](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~nironi/taylor2.pdf) (to order 1) of both factors, then expand. You will get $$
1+\frac{1.1}{n} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) - 1 = \frac{1.1}{n} + o\!\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).
$$

In particular, recall that when $x\to0$ and any fixed $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\begin{align}
\ln(1+x) &= x + o(x) \\
(1+x)^\alpha &= 1+ \alpha x + o(x)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @ Clement : Nice, answer